# SVN commit fails from a bash script

Tags: bash, svn

I am automating a process where i need to add/remove some files from a SVN repository. However the script fails when i try to commit the changes. Some info about my SVN version & the error message that i am receiving is -

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)
compiled May 31 2011, 06:01:42

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
- handles 'http' scheme
- handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
- with Cyrus SASL authentication
- handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
- handles 'file' scheme

$
```

The error that i receive is -

```
svn: '<working directory>/all' is not under version control
```

I do not have a file (or) directory called "all" in the folder. I have tried using the following command as well -

```
svn commit --targets $changelistFile -m $commitMessage
```

where $changelistFile contains all the files that need to be acted upon. They contain both adds & deletes. I still get the same error. If i run the "svn commit" command from the bash shell (after my script has failed) it is successful, however from within the script it fails.

The bash code snippet is -

```
if [[ $numAdded -gt 0 ]] || [[ $numRemoved -gt 0 ]]; then
            svn commit --targets $changelistFile -m $commitMessage
fi
```

Any help in resolving this issue would be very helpful.

update --

The file "$changelistFile" does not contain all . The contents of the file is

```
data/2015_10_05_yyyyy_data.cql
test_consolidated_scripts/test_20151007.cql
```

I tried the command

```
svn commit --targets "$changelistFile" -m $commitMessage
```

and it didn't help either.

Comment: It's slightly off-topic, but Subversion 1.6.x is not supported for two years since Subversion 1.8.0 release: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html

Comment: yea, unfortunately that's the version that's installed on our servers. I could setup my own local subversion but haven't done that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `$commitMessage` happen to contain the word "all"? The file and message should be quoted in case they contain whitespace.

```
svn commit --targets "$changelistFile" -m "$commitMessage"
```

Comment: added the info you had requested as an update to my original post itself. Thought it would be useful additional to the original post itself.

Comment: Actually i solved the problem. Thanks for the tip john. I had to add "" to my $commitMessage. I misread your suggestion as i was blind :-). It solved the issue & i am accepting your suggestion as my answer.